# Setting image from data binding windows mobile c#?

Tags: windows-phone-7, longlistselector

Hello everyone i am new to windows mobile. I am usuing a LongListSelector. I have my class Menu.cs which have the follwing setter and getter :

```
   public Uri Picture
    {
        get { return picture; }
        set
        {
            if (value != picture)
            {
                picture = value;
                NotifyDataHasChanged("Picture");
            }
        }
    }
```

And on my page where i have my LongListSelector :

```
this.menu.Add(new Menu() { Name = "ccc", Picture = new Uri("/Assets/GFX/menuHeaderCO3.png", UriKind.Relative) });

            longListMenuSlide.ItemsSource = menu;
```

And XAML:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="longListMenuSlide" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="594" Margin="0,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Height="78" Width="370" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>


                            </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

Its not working .. I cannot see any images. But If i hard code the image source:

```
<Image Source="/Assets/GFX/menuCO5.png" Height="78" Width="370" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

this works. Any help? I am new to Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: Setting the picture property to a string would also work, The image control binding should take care of this.

Have you set the image "menuHeaderCO3.png" Build Action to "Content"?

If this is does not work, set the image failed event on the control to see what you get for debugging and append the message to the question

```
<Image ImageFailed="ImageFailed" Source="{Binding Picture}" />
```

c#

```
 private void ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorException.Message);
    }
```

Comment: tks actually it was due to Have you set the image "menuHeaderCO3.png" Build Action to "Content"?  i had added it by drag and drop thats y . I had to do is add existing item.